# Getting the OAUTH2 Token

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to retrieve a OAUTH2 token from our IDM server - I've tried several flavors of rudimentary examples, but all of them return a 200 status with no code included.  I can do it with no trouble via postman, using a header of:

```
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

... and sending the client_id, redirect_uri and code parameters.  I get something back that looks like this:

```
{
    "access_token": "abcd...",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Here's the super rudimentary code intended to do no more than see if I can grab the token (at this point):

```
public class Service {

public String getToken() {

    String client_id = "f2e8...";
    String redirect_uri = "https://mysite/";
    String code = "AAAAAA...";

    form = new Form();
    form.param("client_id", client_id);
    form.param("code", code);
    form.param("redirect_uri", redirect_uri);
    JerseyClientBuilder jerseyClientBuilder = new JerseyClientBuilder();
    JerseyWebTarget jerseyWebTarget = 
    jerseyClientBuilder.build().target("https://token-source-site/");
    Response response = jerseyWebTarget.request().post(Entity.form(form));
    return response.toString();
  }
}
```

But all I get back is:

```
InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, 
uri=https://token-source-site/, status=200, reason=OK}}
```

Any thoughts on what Postman might be doing that my code isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to show to the response body when you just call `toString()` on the `Response`. You need to extract the body from it by calling `Response#readEntity`.

But even trying to extract it to a String, you have the problem of still having to parse the string. Best thing to do is to create a POJO for the token response

```
public class AccessTokenResponse {
    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken;

    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    private String tokenType;

    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private long expiresIn;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then you can do

```
Response response = jerseyWebTarget.request().post(Entity.form(form));
return response.readEntity(AccessTokenResponse.class);
```

Make the method return `AccessTokenResponse`, so the client has access to the other properties also.

For this to work, you will need to have the Jackson provider dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this makes great sense.  I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Thanks again @peeskillet, but I'm finding that I get a:
`MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html;charset=utf-8`
when I do a:
`Response response = jerseyWebTarget.request().post(Entity.form(form));
return response.readEntity(AccessTokenResponse.class);`
using the pojo as you described, with the method returning a AccessTokenResponse as you suggested.  Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: Please post the whole stack trace. If you are getting HTML back there is most likely an error on the server side. Check the status code before trying to read try entity