# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type

Tags: java, maven, web-services, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm sending POST request using "resteasy-client" library in **MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE**.

Sample Code :

```
String serviceUrl = "URL";

    ConnectRequest connectRequest = new ConnectRequest();
    connectRequest.setUsername("");
    connectRequest.setPassword("");
    connectRequest.setScope("bearer");
    connectRequest.setGrant_type("");

    Entity<ConnectRequest> entity = Entity.entity(connectRequest,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);

    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(serviceUrl);

    Response response = target.request().post(entity);

    System.out.println("RESP : "+response.toString());
```

Maven Dependencies

```
    <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <resteasy.version>3.0.4.Final</resteasy.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> Connection is working fine and sending correct response while
>   requesting using POSTMAN

[image]

But after requesting using the program it creates error as

Response :

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for
>   content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type

Please help...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use a POJO to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to use the [`javax.ws.rs.core.Form`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Form.html) class.

```
Form connectRequest = new Form()
    .param("username", "...")
    .param("password", "...")
    .param("client_id")
    ...;
```

You can also use `Entity.form(connectionRequest)`, which is shorthand so you don't have to use the `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE`.

---

As an aside, see [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48554534/2587435) for parsing the response. You won't need the dependency. You already have the one for RESTEasy.

Answer (score 0):

I created a set of reader/writers you can import that handle automatic binding of form encoding to java objects: https://github.com/exabrial/form-binding it's a little easier than creating an instance of a Form.